# syntax error when using the END special pattern in AWK

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am a beginner to shell scripting and I am trying to print out the maximum value of an array from a file that I am reading. The code works fine when I don't use the END statement but gives out an error saying that there is a syntax error at or near if statements when the END statement is added. Can you help me find the error in my code?

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
if(FNR==7)
{
natoms=$1+$2+$3
print natoms
}
if(FNR==8) {
       if($1=="selective"){
        start=10
        end=start+natoms-1
        }
       else{
        start = 9
        end = start+natoms-1
        }
       }
if(start<=FNR && FNR<=end){
                
                arr[FNR-10+1] = $3
                print max[arr]
              }
END {print natoms}' POSCAR
```

Comment: I get a syntax error without END, because there are no braces `{ ... }` around the first statement.

Comment: Ohh yes. I see that there are not braces around the second and third if statements as well. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I think you actually want `FNR==7 { natoms = ... } FNR=8 {  ... } start<=FNR && FNR<=end { arr... }`, i.e. replace the `if`s with awk patterns.

Comment: with respect to `The code works fine when I don't use the END` - no it doesn't, it contains syntax errors. If you posted the wrong code by mistake then please [edit] your question to show the real code you want help with.

Answer (score 2):

Get into the habit of using proper indentation, then mistakes become easier to see. A good programming editor can help with this.

As the awk program gets bigger, put the awk code into it's own file. For example, if this is `poscar.awk`

```c
FNR==7 {
    natoms=$1+$2+$3
    print natoms
}
FNR==8 {
    if($1=="selective"){
        start=10
        end=start+natoms-1
    }
    else{
        start = 9
        end = start+natoms-1
    }
}
start<=FNR && FNR<=end {
    arr[FNR-10+1] = $3
    print max[arr]
}
END {print natoms}
```

Then you can run it like

```bsh
awk -f poscar.awk POSCAR
```

---

`print max[arr]` ==> there's no `max` *array* in your code. And awk has no `max()` function. You'll need to keep track of the max value manually.

Comment: Indentation is the key as it reveals the flow of data through the code. A consistently indented code is mostly self documenting.